# Following through a .then() block in Jasmine testing

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jasmine

I'm writing unit tests in Jasmine for an AngularJS project, and getting stuck trying to test behavior that's inside a Promise's `.then()` block.

TLDR version: In the controller, I have a service call that relies on the output of another service call, so one is nested inside the other. In the test file, I set spies on both service calls, and then verify after everything is done that both were called. The possibly-tricky part is that these calls are being triggered by an asynchronous `postMessage` call, but I had that part working before and I'm not sure how it would complicate things now.

The abridged code:
https://gist.github.com/BlackBaud-AlanGordon/6c9d2e26c328d7c585d2

The problem is that nothing inside `getFormInput().then` is getting called. Using console logs, I was able to confirm that loadPage is called, but nothing nested inside the promises is ever called. Am I missing something obvious, or am I just way off base on how I should be testing this?

Comment: could you add a .catch(function(e) { console.log(e); } after the .then? might help.

Comment: btw here $q.all(fooComplete.promise, barComplete.promise]) you have an extra ] in the end, might cause an error, make it fail, and the Promise will silent it since there is no method doing the catch.

Comment: The missing bracket in the promise catcher is a typo on my part when abridging the code for this post.

Comment: I tried adding a console.log(e) to a catch on the .then AND on every place where fooComplete is rejected, and none of them were logged. Also, I forgot to mention - if I put a log statement at the top of loadPage(), then it gets logged 26 times in a row for some reason.

Comment: do you have to do another digest after the first call to make the second call "trigger"?

Comment: Adding another scope digest doesn't change anything.